# When there are >= 10 Messages in inbox add buttons to footer of page as well

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

Right now I have a long list of messages within the jobs->messages tab.  When I checkbox one of these messages I have to scroll all they way to the top to mark the message read / unread.

Can we changes this such that if there are more than say 5 or 10 messages those same buttons appear at the bottom of the list as well?

Right now these buttons are the top right of the list, suggesting that we keep those there but also add these same two button on the bottom right of the list to avoid the amount of scrolling.